# How to calculate total sum in one field in progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a query for calculating total sum in one field but i could get total records. Let me share what i written.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE I AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
FIND FIRST shth_pus_head WHERE shth_pus_head.push_id = "P0000078" NO-LOCK 
NO-ERROR.
FOR EACH shtd_pus_det OF shth_pus_head NO-LOCK:
i = i + 1.
END.
DISPLAY i.
```

What i need is when i calculate total sum in qty column i want sum = 1560.

**(Note- qty column table field is shtd_pus_det.qty)**

[Check the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgOsG.png)

Comment: You have pointlessly added a tag for "progress-bar" again.  This isn't helping your question reach the right audience.  The tags that you want to use for the questions that you have been asking are "progress-4gl" and "openedge".

Comment: I am sorry sir mistakenly i added. I follow you. Sorry again

Comment: I'm just trying to help you get these questions to the proper audience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not calculate a total sum.  It counts the number of records.  To sum up the shtd_pus_det.qty fields in those records you could code something like:

```
define variable tot_qty as integer no-undo.

for each shtd_pus_det no-lock where shtd_pus_det.push_id = "P0000078":
  tot_qty = tot_qty + shtd_pus_det.qty.
end.
display tot_qty.
```